# Disable read cache/buffer for USB mass storage device in Linux

Tags: linux, usb, cache

I have a USB device that presents as a mass storage device, dmesg looks like this:

```
[    4.416584] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Adap ECU Modular ECU      1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[    4.420186] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 131072 512-byte logical blocks: (67.1 MB/64.0 MiB)
[    4.421063] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
[    4.421084] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[    4.422053] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[    4.422067] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[    7.446823] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
```

It does not contain a filesystem, nor is it supposed to. You don't mount it, you merely open and read (in this case) /dev/sda

The issue is when I open and read the device, I will get what I want the first time around, and then each subsequent read I will get (what I assume is) cached data. I make this assumption because the IO light on the device does not flash after the subsequent reads, only on the first read and of course because my `fread()` contains exactly the same data as the first `fread()`.

My code is fine because I compiled it on Windows and specified \.\X: for the file to open and it was able to poll the data just fine with fresh data each call.

So I am going to assume that Linux is caching/buffering the read.

My code looks like this:

```
#define STARTBYTE 272384
#define ENDBYTE 274432
#define NUM_VARS 1024

int main() {
    FILE *input = fopen("/dev/sda", "r+");
    setbuf(input, NULL);
    int exit = 0;
    while (exit < 1) {
        signed short liveBuffer[NUM_VARS];
        fseek(input, STARTBYTE, SEEK_SET);
        fread(liveBuffer, 2, NUM_VARS, input);
        fflush(input);
        // do stuff with the now filled liveBuffer data
    }
    fclose(input);
    return 0;
}
```

I've also tried with `open()` and specifying `O_DIRECT`, with no difference.

The aim is, I open the device (/dev/sda), seek to 272384 bytes. Read 2048 bytes. Re-seek to the same position, read 2048 bytes, etc etc.

If I `fclose()` the file and re-`open()` it, I get fresh data. Except it is SLOW. Approximately 10 samples/sec, when on Windows (without the open/close) I get around 50/sec.

One think I have noticed is that when I let my compiled code run for a few seconds and then kill it (CTRL+C), I then see the activity light on the device flash madly for about the duration I let my code run for.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I've been going at this for days, I think I'm about to hang myself.

Comment: What happens if you read instead from the associated generic SCSI device (`/dev/sg0` in your `dmesg`, number may change)? Is it still cached?

Comment: When I read from `/dev/sg0` I don't get any data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have complicated the matter a little by using the intervening *stdio* layer, and by ignoring the return codes of the functions you are calling.
You can use `O_DIRECT` to get fresh data from the device, but you must respect the obligations that this imposes.

In particular the seek offset, buffer address, and size of i/o must all be multiples of 4096 (or some other power of 2 depending on the device).

If you modify your code to remove your current declaration of liveBuffer and include the following code at the start, you should find it works.

```
#define PAGE 4096
#define STARTBYTE (272384/PAGE*PAGE) // must align
#define OFFSET (272384-STARTBYTE)
#define ITEMSIZE (sizeof(*liveBuffer))
#define LIVEBUFSIZE ((OFFSET+NUM_VARS*ITEMSIZE+PAGE-1)/PAGE*PAGE)

signed short *liveBuffer;
if(posix_memalign((void**)&liveBuffer, PAGE, LIVEBUFSIZE)!=0)
   exit(5);
if (fcntl(fileno(input), F_SETFL, O_DIRECT) == -1)
   exit(6);
```

You must now `fread()` using `LIVEBUFSIZE/ITEMSIZE` rather than NUM_VARS.
As the `STARTBYTE` has to be aligned, you now need to start further into your `liveBuffer` array at `OFFSET/ITEMSIZE` to find the wanted data. 
You should also change all the calls to check for correct return codes.

Comment: Would I be correct in saying that I still `fseek(input, STARTBYTE, SEEK_SET);` as the `STARTBYTE` has changed to your code. But now for read I do `fread(liveBuffer, ITEMSIZE, LIVEBUFSIZE, input);` ?

Comment: yes, you must seek to a multiple of page, and read a multiple of page into a memory area whose address is a multiple of page. You might find more examples if you abandon stdio and just use the basic open, lseek, read of the system. I suppose when they added O_DIRECT they should have thought of integrating it into stdio somehow so this would be done for you.

Comment: THANK YOU. This device uses a page size of 512. I modified that and its working perfectly. You my friend, are awesome.